# Is there any decent alternative for Launchy?

Tags: software-rec

For many years I was using [Launchy](https://www.launchy.net) for Windows and Linux. I notice that launchy is having issues with popping up and losing focus on the input field. This happened  on Linux Mint 18, and in Debian with Gnome Wayland now.
Is there any alternative for this tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try [Albert](https://github.com/albertlauncher/albert). [image: see]

It's an app similar to spotlight in OSX. You can easily search and launch apps with this tool.

You have to install it via a PPA:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/albert
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install albert
```

### Slingscold Launcher and Synapse are also good alternatives.

[image]

[image: sdsd]

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Launchy, but from the description on the homepage, [rofi](https://github.com/DaveDavenport/rofi) may be a suitable replacement.

It does not support all the use cases of Launchy out of the box, but it can be extended with scripts. By default, it allows quick switching between windows, launching applications (from PATH or via `.desktop` files) or starting up ssh sessions.